# Is there a way to wait/delay rendering until for #Each-Helper is done with provided model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**Background:** 
In my application I want a list of tags that's being displayed on every page of the website. Therefore I added a component to my application.hbs and gave the model, which I received in my application-route (from Firebase), into it:

application.hbs:

```
{{#tag-list-slider model=model}}{{/tag-list-slider}}
```

application.js (Route):

```
model() {
    return this.store.findAll('tag')
}
```

**Problem:**
In my component I want to display the given model with the [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). This works fine as long as I have static content like this:

conponent.hbs:

```
  <ul class="tag-slider">
      <li class="listItem">foo</li>
      <li class="listItem">foo</li>
      <li class="listItem">foo</li>
      <li class="listItem">foo</li>
  </ul>
```

The slider works great for this, even with images.
Now my problem comes up as soon as I want to fill that list with the content of the model I put into the component:

```
  <ul class="tag-slider">
      {{#each model as |tag|}}
        <li class="listItem">foo</li>
      {{/each}}    
  </ul>
```

...and the slider just won't work.
I put the "logic" for the slider in my component.js and there I used the *didInsertElement()*-hook:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function() {
  $('.tag-slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    maxSlides: 2,
    slideMargin: 50
  });
});
```

As you can see I even tried to use 'afterRender', but that doesn't do anything for me.

**(I think) I nailed the problem down** to the slider not having all the list-items when the page gets rendered. For that I combined the two cases from above and filled the list with both dynamic content from the #each-helper and the static html-content. In my *didInsertElement()* I wrote the count of all the list-items to the console:

```
  var listLengh = $('.listItem').length;
  console.log(listLengh);
  // try again, just for safety:
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function() {
    var listLengh = $('.listItem').length;
    console.log(listLengh);
  });
```

and for both console.logs the output is "4" although it should be 8 (4 static + 4 dynamic list-items) because I think the count happens before the #each-helper adds the dynamic content to the page. (Which is strange because I thought thats the didInsertElement-hook was for).

So I'm looking for ways to delay the whole bxslider-process untill my #each-helper is done with loading the model-data to the template but I couldnt really find anything thus far.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation seems to indicate the bxslider requires all elements to be present, so your guess seems good. It should be good in your example however, because normally returning the promise in the `model` hook will pause the transition until the promise is fully resolved.

Still, if `model` is updated at any point, your slider will break.

Perhaps for some reason this is what is happening. Perhaps something in your app causes the template to be rendered and model to be updated after. How about we ensure your component does not break when `model` changes? Fortunately, bxslider provides a `reloadSlider` method we can call to tell it the list of slides changed.

```
watchModel: Ember.observer('model.[]', function () {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'reloadSlider');
}),
reloadSlider: function () {
    $('.tag-slider').bxSlider().reloadSlider();
}
```

The first method will be invoked everytime the model changes (the whole list is updated, or an item is added/removed). It will schedule the second method to be invoked after the DOM has been updated by Ember. The second method will invoke the [reloadSlider](http://bxslider.com/options#reloadSlider) method.

This, however, will cause problems if `model` is updated in between component creation and insertion into the DOM. To fix it, you should instead register the observer with `addObserver` from your `didInsertElement` hook and unregister it with `removeObserver` from your `willDestroyElement` hook.

I cannot test, but I believe it should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I can assure is, that the model does not change in my example since I'm never touching the database behind it. Thats why my guess was that the list-elements are just not yet present in the template when the bxSlider is called. However I'm not home right now but I'll try your solution in a few hours and update here.

Comment: Hey again, so I wanted to try the reload()-method on a normal static slider to see how it works before I used it for the dynamic stuff. Unfortunately I already ran into problems there: For comparisons sake I posted the content of my component right here for a very simple example: http://pastebin.com/Z6i298AF
The thing that happens here though is that instead of properly reloading the slider my DOM changes from this http://i.imgur.com/lmTkLKz.jpg to that http://i.imgur.com/YcOKAyk.jpg . (similiar problem to here:  https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/762 ?) Ideas?

Comment: If that's an issue with the bxslider widget, there is not much you can do but wait for it to be fixed. You could try to only call `.bxSlider` once in `didInsertElement` and store the object so you can re-use it without calling `.bxSlider` again, since it seems to be one of the things that trigger the bxslider bug.

Comment: Alright, the observer-approach worked! Here is the final code of my component: http://pastebin.com/nEAZr1w9  ....one note note on some weird behaviour of the slider: Initially I wanted to use a list to contain the slider-content (see original post). Weirdly enough my tags appeared to be too "short" (its basically just a word per list-item, tags eh..) and so the slider did render but no content was shown (even though in the dom list-items had the tags/text in them). So I switched to divs and it worked! I hope I made the problem somewhat clear. Anyway, it works, thanks alot for your help!